# Динамическая переменная в групповом роуте Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Подскажите как использовать, динамическую переменную в групповых маршрутах Laravel, например:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang?}'], function () {
//..
});
```

из middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){

$lang = session('locale');

 App::setLocale($lang);

return $next($request);      
});
```

так же пытался получить данные прям в префиксе но тоже получаю null

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>  config('app.locale')], function () {
//..
});
```

или

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>  session('locale')], function () {
//..
});
```

Задаю все отдельным маршрутом через сессию

```
Route::get('setlocale/{locale}', function ($locale) {

session(['locale' => $locale]);

return redirect()->back();

})->name('setlocale');
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.